# Blocking bots / hackers from accessing newsletter subscription

Tags: magento-1.7, newsletter, security

I am getting massive amounts of fake newsletter subscriptions - mostly a randomly generated Yahoo email address. I've looked through the logs and there are 50+ IP addresses, seems like it's from a botnet. Anyway, does anyone have any ideas how I could stop this? Should it be done on a server level or at a codebase level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know two options you have:

1. Add a fake field, with a cool name, like name or url, make it invisible with JS or CSS (something the bot can't interpret), then the bot fill this field but a human does not and then check whether the field is filed, if it is, it is a bot.

   For your luck, we already did something like this, but I just saw, newsletter registration is missing. But you can only register for newsletter (in core magento) if you are registered. So I can only inspire you: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/HoneySpam/
2. The second thing you can do (but there is NO REASON IN THE WORLD TO DO SO(!!)) is using a captcha. Bad idea, bad technique, bad behavier, a lot of problems for your customers willing to register for the newsletter. So this is more a plan Y. Shortly before plan Z disable the form.

Comment: +1 for the HoneyPot approach. but I really don't like the captcha thing. You should write it in a smaller font so only the desperate people read it. :)

Comment: HoneyPots are good, but unfortunately this attack seems to only target the newsletter email input field.

Comment: Oh, did you try? This is hard. Then you can try with an XSS field, when they only send the newsletter-field, they might forget the XSS field :)